# command line piping output to command on next line

Tags: unix

I'm pretty new to Unix and am having trouble figuring out how to break a long single line command onto multiple lines piping results from one to the next.

I get that output goes to stdout, but don't know if theres a way to reference it from another line.

For example: The following script concatenates all scss files in a directory puts two returns between them, but rather than using | and just making the script longer, Id like to use it on the next line. Is there a way to do that?

```
> for f in dev/scss/*.scss; do cat $f; echo; echo; done
> <use output from above here>
```

Thanks for any help

Comment: Store the output to a variable: `foo=$(for f in dev/scss/*.scss; do cat $f; echo; echo; done`. Then use `$foo`.

Comment: Use "$foo" to preserve newlines (write is as "${foo}", good habit).

Answer (score 2):

You can use backslashes to break commands up into multiple lines.

```
for f in dev/scss/*.scss; do cat "$f"; echo; echo; done \
    | additional-processing
```

After certain operators like `&&`, `||`, and `|` pipes the backslash isn't required. Bash knows the command is unfinished. If you put the `|` on the previous line you don't need a backslash.

```
for f in dev/scss/*.scss; do cat "$f"; echo; echo; done |
    additional-processing
```

You could chain together a large number of commands this way.

```
for f in dev/scss/*.scss; do cat "$f"; echo; echo; done |
    foo |
    bar |
    baz
```

If the loop gets unwieldy you should also consider wrapping it in a function call. I like that approach because it means you don't need to cram everything into a small number of lines. You can give the loop more breathing room with each command on a separate line.

```
loop() {
    for f in dev/scss/*.scss; do
        cat "$f"
        echo
        echo
    done
}
```

That lets you shorten your pipeline to something more readable like:

```
loop | foo | bar | baz
```

---

<sup>P.S. Always quote variable expansions. Write `cat "$f"` so file names with whitespace and other special characters are handled correctly.</sup>

Comment: Thanks John. That cleared it up. Final question: the "dev/scss" folder might conceivably have subfolders, so what option or additional command would I need to make the loop recursive? Can it be done with a glob pattern?

Comment: You should ask that as a separate question. But google it first. I'm sure it's been answered before.

Answer (score 0):

The most direct answer is this:

```
IFS='\0'
result=`for f in dev/scss/*.scss; do cat $f; done`
echo $result
```

The `IFS` is there to avoid having bash mess with your spaces and line endings by reinterpreting them as item boundaries. (Without it, you end up with `echo $result` dumping everything quite unhelpfully on one line.)

But the wildcard is expanded in place, and depending on how many files match the glob, you might end up with a command that is too long to process. You're almost certainly better off using `find`, but it also depends on what you want the contents of those files for. There may be a simpler way to do what you're trying to accomplish without having to store the contents of all files in an intermediate variable first.

Comment: That should be `IFS=$'\0'` or, simpler, `IFS=`. But the right answer is to quote `echo "$result"`, not change `$IFS`.